# Bootstrap Alert div remains when there are no messages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an error message alert bar in my website, I'm trying to make this only appear whenever there is a message to display as currently it remains even when there are no messages. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my alert..

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your conditions under `alert` div, like:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}

<div class="alert alert-success">
    <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @richard0096 If this answer helped you, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Just waiting for the timer to run out.

Comment: @richard0096 No Issues!